# How do I list files with edit locks on a network drive using a shell and associated tools?

Tags: shell, dos, locking, edit

How do I list files with edit locks on a network drive using a shell and associated tools?

I think net file has to be run on the server,  and I'm looking to do this from any box on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

"Display all the open shared files on a server and the lock-id NET FILE

Close a shared file (disconnect other users and remove file locks) NET FILE id /CLOSE"

And this was tested on an xp workstation.  Operates fine, but I am not sure how UAC would effect it.